# Does intellij offer master branch protection

Tags: intellij-idea, git-commit, git-push

I want to know if Intellji offers master branch protection and if so how do I implement it?

**Scenario**,

I checkout the master branch from a repo and make a small change but forget to create a feature branch ... how can I protect myself from committing and pushing those changes directly to the master branch via the commit option on IntelliJ (cmd and k)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no option in IDE to prevent commiting and pushing to some branch, but there is a mechanism that allows you to prevent force Push to a certain branch by making it `Protected`

It can be found under [Preferences | Version Control | Git](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-git.html)

There is a feature request to block a push to a regular branch:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150759